# adjust the margin to be 1"

Tags: margins, geometry, marginpar, layout

I am working on my dissertation, I am using a custom document class you can find it [here](https://github.com/soooleh/dissertationLaTeX)

I am trying to make the margin 1" from each side. I tried to use geometry but didn't work

```
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
```

I am getting this error

```
Package geometry Error: \paperwidth (0.0pt) too short.
```

This is what I have on the cls. file

```
\pdfpageheight 11in
\pdfpagewidth 8.5in

%\paperheight 11in
%\paperwidth 8.5in
\voffset 0pt
\topmargin 0pt
\headheight 0pt
\headsep 0pt
\textheight 9.0in

\oddsidemargin 0in
\evensidemargin 0in
\marginparwidth 0.0in
\textwidth 6.5in%5.95in
\widowpenalty \@MM
\clubpenalty \@MM

\def\ps@headings{%
  \let\@oddfoot\@empty
  \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
  \let\@mkboth\markboth
  \def\chaptermark##1{%
    \markright {\uppercase{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ \fi
        ##1}}}}
\def\ps@myheadings{%
  \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
  \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
  \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
  \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
  \let\chaptermark\@gobble
  \let\sectionmark\@gobble}
\pagestyle{plain}
```

I am getting a 1-inch margin from the right side and the left side, but the top and bottom aren't 1 inch!

how can I fix it?

========

Updated

Even after using the following:

```
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
```

I still feel that the bottom margin isn't 1"

[image]

I feel that the page number is 1" from the bottom where it should be 0.75"

Comment: Try to write 'letterpaper,' just before 'margin=1in'.

Comment: Why would you upload a .zip file to github? The whole point of github is to be able to see the source and suggest modifications to it. I was going to suggest the same thing as Raffaele, but I think that only works for the mainmatter, as the document class has manually set margins in the frontmatter. There are also errors in the way the ToC, LoF and LoT are handled, but I didn't investigate those in any detail. Did your University provide the .cls or did you make it? Your University probably wants it used as is. They tend to be fussy about that.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro I think it worked, is there any way to double-check that I am actually getting a 1-inch margin?

Comment: @frabjous I updated the files in Github. The .cls isn't provided by the university, one of my friends made it. In fact, the university pointed out that I need to fix the ToC, LoF, and LoT.

Comment: Put this line of code in the preamble '\usepackage{showframe}'

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro after showing the frame, I can see that the problem is still there. Please see the main post, I uploaded the result.

Comment: @soooleh I think the result is like wuat you want; 1 inch of margin. On more pages of your document is easier to see that.

Comment: If this is an unofficial document class you don't mind editing, I would just strip out all the stuff having to do with margins, page size and dimensions inside it (I think there is more than just what is posted above though), and let the geometry package do everything related to that.